# Wrap <ul> menu in <hr /> tags

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu using an unordered list.I would like to wrap it in two `<hr />` elements.The problem is the second hr doesn't appear after the `<ul>` but instead next to the first one:

[image]

```css
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <hr />
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
</header>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: is the ul/li floated ? if yes then apply a clearing technique

Comment: As @FabrizioCalderan said, [clear after `floating`](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/css/main.css#L166).

Comment: I agree, `clear:both` should fix it. I would add that you  can use borders to save adding `hr`.

Comment: is it important that these are <hr>s? If not you could use a wrapping div with border-top: 2px solid grey; and border-bottom: 2px solid grey;

Comment: reference: [Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` on the `li` which is unnecessary as using `float: left;` will take it out of the flow mitigating the need for `display: inline-block;`.

Applying `float: left;` to the `li` also means that the `hr` will need to be cleared to ensure it displays after the `ul`.

As `display: inline-block;` will ensure the `li` are displayed horizontally, you can simply remove `float: left;` from the `li` without needing to clear the `hr`.

```css
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying `inline-block` to your `li` then you don't need to use `float:left`, if you use `float:left` you need to clear the next element that comes after, in this case `<hr />`

```css
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* float:left */
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <hr />
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
   .header ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

header li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:10%;
  background-color:gray;
  padding:10px;
}
ul li:hover
{
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

ul li
{display:inline-block;}a
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/k5yw74j5/1/)